# Xamarin.Forms Long Press Effect - How to set the Command in Code Behind (NO XAML)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, command, long-press

I'm using this solution for handling the long tap event: https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/

It works fine when I use XAML, but I need to use code behind only. How can I add this command to the `Image` in the code behind?

Here is the code that creates my image:

```
var image = new Image
{
    ClassId = item.Path,
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
    Source = item.ThumbNailImage,
    Rotation = 90,
    Margin = 10,
    GestureRecognizers = { _tgr },
    //Command here, but how?
};
```

Comment: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating `image.Effects.Add(...)`

Comment: "Cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Command' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Effect'"

Comment: what even is `_tgr` you should put every code in your original post and write what you tried so far. Why do you try to add the effect as a command?

Comment: I want single tap for select the picture and long tap to show pictures details like file size etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties#consuming-the-effect) on Microsoft's website is very helpful in explaining how to set attached properties in code.

So according to the example, your code should look something like this:

```
image.Effects.Add(new LongPressedEffect());
LongPressedEffect.SetCommand(image, myCommand);
```

Where `myCommand` is an `ICommand`.

This should create the `LongPressedEffect`, add it to the image, and then set the attached `ICommand` that determines the behavior.